# Dynamically display images using for loop in ListBox in c#

Tags: c#, for-loop, listbox, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to display dynamically Images in a ListBox, There is an image URL, I have to show images from that URL.

Here is my URL:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
var nodes = doc.Descendants("row").ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Count; i++)
{
   Id = nodes[i].Element("Id").Value;

   string uri = "https://www.myabc.com/ABC/getDocument.htm?name=" + name + "&password=" + pwd + "&Id=" + Id";


List<LIST> list = new List<LIST>();

list = (from query in doc.Descendants("row")
        select new LIST
        {
           img = uri
        }
}

listBox1.DataContext = list;
```

How do I show it in ListBox?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: What images? What ListBox? Your code has neither of these things.

Comment: @BenRobinson see my edit, I am trying to display in ListBox, but something I am doing wrong. Can you help me out? Thanks!!

Comment: Zoom, because I have binded some other details in listbox. Do you have other suggestion? Please give me. I am stuck here. Thanks!!